# jQuery Call Function Only Works Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Found answer but different with my question. So there's my function:

```
function load_few_comments(){
    var t = '<div style="text-align:center"><img src="' + theme_url + '/assets/img/loading.gif"/></div>';
    $("#few-comments").html(t);
    var e = $("#few-comments").attr("url"),
        i = $("#few-comments").attr("post_id");
    $.post(e, {
        post_id: i
    }, function(t) {
        $("#few-comments").html(t)
    })
}
```

And it's called in ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    load_few_comments();
});
```

Also in success load event:

```
$(".load-more").click(function(t) {
    t.preventDefault();
    var i = $(this).attr('uri-request');
    $.post(i, {}, function(t) {
        if ("NO_MORE" == t) {
            var i = '<div class="alert alert-info" style="display:inline;position:relative;"><strong>No more post</strong> <a data-dismiss="alert" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></div><br /><br/><img src="' + theme_url + '/assets/img/no_more.png" alt="no more post" />';
            $(".bottom-end").html(i)
        } else {
            load_few_comments() //<================ Call Function Again Here
        }
        e = 1;
    });
});
```

But it's look only once works and only applied in first element.

Here is screenshot:
[image]

That's all and thank you...